# Negative/Inverted Printing - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, printing, printer, brother-printer

Tried printing something on my Brother DCP-L2520DW series (Black Laser printer).
But for some reason, it's printing on negative/inverted colors (like with black background and white text). I've printed some stuff on it before and it was working fine, so this problem is quite recent.

Printed on LibreOffice Writer, Fox PDF Reader, and even printing "Print Test Page" has the same result. It's connected through Wi-Fi and every other device connected with it is printing fine.

I concluded that the problem might be on my computer (ASUS G752, Windows 10). Check the internet for solutions to the same problem and no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "...every other device connected with it is printing fine"

That's good. You can already rule out a problem with the printer itself.

Reinstalling the printer driver on the problematic PC would be the best place to start.

Comment: Well for some reason it didn't work for the first 3 times I reinstall the driver. It was a problem for me for the whole week. But 4th try is the charm I guess. Never encountered this kind of problem before.

Comment: Nice work! ️ 